# Ruby: class inside module take place priority over module?

Tags: ruby

```
module TestModule
  NAME = "Ruby"
  def self.class_method
    puts "this is modules method"
  end
  def instances_method
    puts "this is instances methods"
  end
  class MyClass
    puts "this is class inside module"
  end
end

puts TestModule::NAME
puts TestModule.class_method
puts TestModule::MyClass

Output:
this is class inside module
Ruby
this is modules method
```

It Should be :
    Ruby
    this is modules method
    this is class inside module

Is there any priority in ruby between class and module. As ruby is a interpreter so class (class MyClass) should be execute at last.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not about priority, your `puts` call in class is outside any method. Interpreter reads whole file first, thats why it outputs `this is class inside module` before any of these calls

```
puts TestModule::NAME
puts TestModule.class_method
puts TestModule::MyClass
```

You can test this:

```
module TestModule
  puts 'reading module'

  class MyClass
    puts 'reading class'
  end
end
```

and you'll see:

```
reading module
reading class
```

And `puts TestModule::MyClass` this call won't output puts inside your class as you may expect. So just wrap your class puts in instance or class method and call it as `TestModule::MyClass.new.instance_method` or `TestModule::MyClass.class_method` correspondingly.